# What is the best input for 'price' in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, input, numbers

I am using a custom form_helper with all the new html5 input types, including `<input type="number">`
I was wondering if there is a better input for this, because the `number` field does not work with decimals only with full numbers.

the current input I use for this is like:

```
<tr>
<td><?= form_label('Prijs:');?></td>
<td><?= form_number('aanbiedingprijs'); ?></td>
</tr>
```

I think there is a better way but I can't find something.

Comment: use standard `text` and the check if via `JS` and `PHP` for best result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<input type="number" name='nums' id='nums' step="any" />
```

if you want positive numbers
   min=0

Comment: That will work. Is the validation error gone in chrome when I add step="any" ? I guess so?